# VSCode debugger not stopping on Typescript breakpoints

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, source-maps

[I have a Lerna monorepo with 2 modules(packages): `ps` and `cli`.](https://github.com/komninoschat/vscode-debug-weird)

`ps` just exports a function `whatever` which `cli` imports.

When I try to debug this code using VSCode, however, my breakpoints stop on the generated Javascript files instead of my source Typescript files.

[image]

This has bothered me for hours and I have extensively played around with my `tsconfig.json` and `launch.json` as well as using `vscode-pwa-analyzer` to see that VSCode is able to detect my source TS code but I cannot figure out a fix.

EDIT: I am using the following setup:
macOS Big Sur v11.1
Node.js v14.8.0
Typescript v4.1.3

And [here](https://easyupload.io/o6jzdr) is a dump file of my above debug you can load to [vscode-pwa-analyzer](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-pwa-analyzer/index.html).
[image]
I can see here that I get some Unbound Breakpoint errors.

Comment: Looks like the issue as you pointed to the function declaration. Try to the 1st line of the body function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated the *problem*, but I would say that this is the expected behavior.

Actually setting a breakpoint on a function declaration makes no sense.
If you change your `whatever` function as a sync function (i.e. `function whatever(): void`) you will see that VSCode doesn't let you to break on that line.

In the special case of an `async` function we know that the function body is actually wrapped in a `Promise`. Probably in this special case the typescript debugger let us to set a breakpoint on a function declaration line to let us check what happens outside the `Promise` wrap.

Comment: You have to run `lerna bootstrap` to build the packages and link them together and then just run the `test` debug config from VSCode. Yes, the `.js` files are supposed to be loaded by the debugger and through the source maps, mapped to the source `.ts` files so my breakpoints work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with VS code stopping inside .js files, instead of .ts. My issue was that I was running VS code debugger (with F5 key), while also having "tsc -w main.ts" running in my terminal. As soon as I stopped the terminal tsc command and rerun vs code debugger - it started to stop in .ts files. Hope it will help.